# Mongodb Loop Query.Matches by .NET MVC

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I get the `fruitlist` value and I want to loop the `Query.Matches` for more matching

```
string fruitlist = "orange,apple,berry";
IMongoQuery query = Query.And(
                    Query.GTE("memberinfo.height", 170),
                    Query.LTE("memberinfo.height",179),
                    Query.GTE("memberinfo.weight",50),
                    Query.LTE("memberinfo.weight",59),
                    Query.Matches("memberinfo.fruits.name","orange")
);

MongoCursor mongocursor = nsdb.GetCollection("XXDB", "Member").Find(query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("memberinfo.createtimestamp"));
```

The Exmaple Collection Structure

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "name" : "John",
    "height": 170,
    "weight": 55,
    "memberinfo" : {
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "apple","reason" : null },
                     {"name" : "orange","reason" : null},
                     {"name" : "berry","reason" : null}
        ],
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "456",
    "name" : "Cena",
    "height" : 160,
    "weight": 90,
    "memberinfo" : {
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "berry","reason" : null},
                     {"name" : "orange","reason" : null}
        ],
    }
}
```

Any suggestion to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: show us your collection as well

Comment: @ShumiGupta added example collection structure

Comment: @ShumiGupta did u know ?

Comment: have you tried using $in ?

Comment: @ShumiGupta use `$in` in `db.find` right ? but I have other query like `GTE` and `LTE` , any suggestion ?

Comment: use can use $gte and $lte for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138689/discussion-between-im-happy-and-shumi-gupta).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138692/discussion-between-im-happy-and-shumi-gupta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have the solution =)

```
string fruitlist = "orange,apple,berry";
string[] cat_sel = fruitlist.Split(',');

var andList = new List<IMongoQuery>();

foreach (var attribute in cat_sel)
{
    andList.Add(Query.Matches("memberinfo.fruits.name", attribute));
}

IMongoQuery query = Query.And(
                Query.GTE("memberinfo.height", 170),
                Query.LTE("memberinfo.height",179),
                Query.GTE("memberinfo.weight",50),
                Query.LTE("memberinfo.weight",59),
                Query.And(andList)
);

MongoCursor mongocursor = nsdb.GetCollection("XXDB", "Member").Find(query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("memberinfo.createtimestamp"));
```